# localCompare for Integers

Tags: javascript, numbers, integer, compare

I'm using localCompare to compare some strings, those strings are numbers. I want the order to be numeric. How can I do this?

## Sort function:

```
requestAmountEl.find('optgroup').each(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    options = $this.children('option');
    options.detach().sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.value.localeCompare(a.value);
    }).appendTo($this);
});
```

## Result:

```
<optgroup label="6 Months">
    <option value="2000">$2,000</option>
    <option value="11000">$11,000</option>
    <option value="10000">$10,000</option>
    <option value="1000">$1,000</option>
</optgroup>
```

Right now it'll sort 2000, 10000, 11000, 1000.

Answer (score 8):

[String.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) has what you need.  Pass in the numeric option and it will treat your strings as numbers:

```
['2000', '11000', '10000', '1000'].sort(
  (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {'numeric': true})
);
```

... results in:

```
["1000", "2000", "10000", "11000"]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Solution:

```
requestAmountEl.find('optgroup').each(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    options = $this.children('option');
    options.detach().sort(function(a,b) {
        if (parseInt(b.value) > parseInt(a.value)) return 1;
        else if (parseInt(b.value) < parseInt(a.value)) return -1;
        else return 0;
    }).appendTo($this);
});
```