# Date column is not sorted ascending or descending

Tags: javascript

I have a column for number, births and types. If I want to order by Number or Type form ASC or DESC it works perfectly but if I want to order by Birth it doesn't. Is like if I click on "Birth" column, it order by "Number" column I don't know very well what is happening, I have little experience with Javascript, I'm practicing.

```js
let sortDirection = 1;

$(document).ready(() => {
    $('th').each(function (columna) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            let registros = $('table').find('tbody > tr').get();

            registros.sort(function (a, b) {
                let valor1 = parseInt($(a).children('td').eq(columna).text().toUpperCase(), 16);
                let valor2 = parseInt($(b).children('td').eq(columna).text().toUpperCase(), 16);

                return valor1 < valor2 ? -1 : valor1 > valor2 ? 1 : 0
            });
            
            if (sortDirection === 1) registros.reverse();            
            sortDirection *= -1; // change direction

            $.each(registros, function (indice, elemento) {
                $('tbody').append(elemento);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Birth</th>
        <th>Type</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2022-09-22</td>
        <td>A</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2022-09-26</td>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2022-09-21</td>
        <td>A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>2022-09-29  </td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2022-09-27</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2022-09-30</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Use the dataTable lib for this, https://datatables.net/

Comment: I followed the installation steps but I did not see any change in my table

Comment: Hey @Grumpy can you help me with something of DataTables? I recently posted and issue with Excel button

Answer (score 0):

I found something.

```js
console.log(parseInt("2022-09-22".toUpperCase(), 16));
// 8226
console.log(parseInt("2022-09-26".toUpperCase(), 16));
// 8226
console.log(parseInt("2022".toUpperCase(), 16));
// 8226
console.log(parseInt("-".toUpperCase(), 16));
// NaN


// -----------------------------


// Like this?
// dictionary-order
console.log(
["2022-09-26","2022-09-25","2022-09-27"].sort(
    (a, b) => a.localeCompare(
        b, 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' })
));
// ['2022-09-25', '2022-09-26', '2022-09-27']

// numeric sort
console.log(
['2000', '11000', '10000', '1000'].sort(
    (a, b) => a.localeCompare(
        b, undefined, {'numeric': true})
));
// ['1000', '2000', '10000', '11000']
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54218232/11634537